# How to change the selection tip of custom cursor using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cursor

In my website, I am using a color picker jquery plugin for picking colors from an image.I have change the cursor to an eyedropper icon using CSS. Right now,while clicking on the image,the color pointed by the upper part of cursor is picked.Since it is eyedrope cursor, i need to use its lower part to pick colors. Please help me out.

This is the cursoram that using : [image]

Thanks

Comment: better post a fiddle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom CSS cursor click point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649608/custom-css-cursor-click-point)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cursor:url(http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourcursorname.cur) 0 16,default;
```

Tell it where to set the x y coords in your css when declaring the cursor.

Comment: Yes. Note however, that if this is necessary, there is an error in the .cur file! The information is supposed to be in there. These coordinates are meant to be used only with ordinary image files like .png, .gif etc (although they do override the coordinates from the .cur file if present).