# Change where mouse is actually clicking

Tags: css, mouse-cursor

Is it possible with CSS to tell the browser that with this new cursor that the click point is not actually at 0x0y but actually 3x-20y.

Looking though all of the options, I did not see one to do such a thing.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

This would be helpful to be used in conjunction with either

[Javascript library to Change cursor color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397654/javascript-library-to-change-cursor-color)

OR

`cursor: url();`

Answer (score 2):

css3 supports this... `cursor: url(curser.cur) 3 -20, auto;`
The .cur format also embeds the hotspot...

This has already been covered in length here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649608/custom-css-cursor-click-point)

Comment: A shame, looks like that won't work with being recolored then.  I will have to modify the Canvas to trick it.